# Execute Javascript after Div populated with Javascript has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to exceute a javascript function after another div that has been popupated by javascript has loaded. The div has been populated first with javascript is '#am-events-booking'. The function i am trying to use is:

```
$(window).load(function ()
{
  var i = setInterval(function ()
  {
    if ($('#am-events-booking').length)
    {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
  }, 1000);
  alert('Page is loaded');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use `$(document).ready()` to run code after the page has loaded. Not sure what the difference is, but at least then it works.

Furthermore you need to use `.text()` to get the text inside an element.

Working code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = setInterval(function() {
    if ($('#am-events-booking').text().length) {
      clearInterval(i);
      console.log('Text detected!');
    } else {
      console.log('Waiting...');
    }
  }, 1000);
  console.log('Page is loaded');
});

setTimeout(loadText, 2200);

function loadText() {
  $('#am-events-booking').html("<h2>Hello</h2>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="am-events-booking"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(findDiv);
    
function findDiv() {
  if($('#am-events-booking').is(':visible')){ // if the div is visible
     alert('Page is loaded'); 
  } else {
  console.log("loading...");
    setTimeout(findDiv, 50); // wait 50ms, 
  }
}

$('body').html('<div id="am-events-booking"></div>');
```

```html
<body></body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you can use is :visible form JQuery to check if div is added or not